# "null" String .equals("null") return false java (JOptionPane)

Tags: java, string, equals, joptionpane

Ok sorry If I am making a duplicate, but i really looked through the site and did not seem to find something similar to my problem. Or at least it is working for other people but not for me.

My main problem is that I use a JOptionPane, and I store the result in a String. When the close button is clicked, the value stored in the string is "null" as I noticed it in the console.

```
String addedItemName = (String)addItemPane.showInputDialog(null,"Select item to add to basket","Add Item",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,items,"Select Item");
System.out.println("added item : " + addedItemName);
```

gets me this result in console :

> added item : null

Therefore, as I am looking to know when the close button was clicked by comparing my addedItemName String to a "null" String.
Which seems to never work, and quite frustrates me because I don't really get it.
Here are a few other tests I made in order to show how every different way I try it but it still doesn't work.

```
        String nullString = "null";
                      
        boolean test1 = Objects.equals(addedItemName, nullString);
        boolean test2 = Objects.equals(nullString,addedItemName);
        boolean test3 = nullString.equals(addedItemName);
        boolean test4 = nullString.equalsIgnoreCase(addedItemName);

        System.out.println(addedItemName);
        System.out.println(nullString);

        System.out.println(test1);
        System.out.println(test2);
        System.out.println(test3);
        System.out.println(test4);
```

With following console output when i click the close button :

> null
>
> null
>
> false
>
> false
>
> false
>
> false

So Basically, console shows me that the addedItemName is "null" when the close button is clicked, but when I compare it to a "null" String, it somehow never is equal.

Thanks for anyone that will show me how stupid I actually am and why it doesn't work for a goofy simple reason.

(also little issue but don't know if it's important : those lines of equality testing return nullPointerException error even if the strings get the value)

```
   boolean test1 = addedItemName.equals(nullString);
   boolean test2 = addedItemName.equalsIgnoreCase(nullString);

   System.out.println(addedItemName);
   System.out.println(nullString);
```

output :

> null
>
> null
>
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: `null` and `"null"` are completely different...

Comment: null and "null" are indeed completely different, but in my case it is only "null" because they are only strings aren't they? @LouisWasserman

Comment: What do you mean, "they are only strings"?  You can have a String that is null and not "null".

Comment: Yeah I actually just got it thanks to @IEE1394's answer, but that concept was totally abstract to me until now. thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null-String must be:

```
String nullString = null;
```

cause 'null' means a not referenced object (keep in mind everything in java is a object)

```
String nullString = "null";
```

is a valid reference to a String which contains the letters **null**
Your output is a little bit obfuscating, cause

```
System.out.println("added item : " + null);
```

results in the output you saw. Thats cause the String concatination:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11

> ...Now only reference values need to be considered. If the reference
>   is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters
>   n, u, l, l). Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an
>   invocation of the toString method of the referenced object with no
>   arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method is null,
>   then the string "null" is used instead.

Comment: Wow thanks,  that was actually really helpful, super fast, and got me to understand the problem in addition to solving it.
Thanks a lot, you rock ! :)